# Can't get the DOM in a react app using testcafe

Tags: dom, automated-tests, create-react-app, testcafe, react-scripts

I'm new into testcafe. I have a `react` app which was made by `create-react-app`, and I'm trying to do very simple function:
`await t.expect(ReactSelector('ReactHighcharts').exists.ok()`
I figured out that no matter what component I put inside the selector I get `flase`.

When I explored more, I saw that `react-scripts` probably minifies/uglifies by his `webpack`, my code, and that's
why I can't get the `DOM`.
Am I right? if yes - how can I disable it? if not, I'd like to understand why the `DOM` is unreachable.

Comment: The fact that 'react-scripts' minified your code is not a problem. Make sure you specify the component name correctly. To check that, set the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=ru) browser extension and inspect the component name with it.

Comment: I wrote it correctly as it is in the code and it didnt work. Do i still need this tool?

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly set the `displayName` property for a component or consider testing the dev build.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname